# how change the picture by clicking on it

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have two images of the same type one blue and the other pink to simulate the click on the image, so when I click on the image it calls one screen without first calling the other image.
what I want is before calling the other screen, clicking on the initial image that is blue change to pink and only then calls the screen.

```
 <Image x:Name="CmdCalendario" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="calendarioFiscallivre.png"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
```

So I would like to click on the image before changing to the pink image that is in the code behind and then call the screen.

```
  var CalendarioClick = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            CalendarioClick.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                CmdCalendario.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Agtmovel.Img.calendarioFiscalpressed.png");
                Navigation.PushAsync(new CalendarioFiscal());

            }; CmdCalendario.GestureRecognizers.Add(CalendarioClick);
```

Comment: And what isn't working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, but when I click on the image it calls the other screen so before calling the screen does not show the other image that is pink. so it only shows the image after calling the screen and if I press the back button change picture. @GeraldVersluis

Comment: Maybe removing `Navigation.PushAsync(new CalendarioFiscal());` will stop it from navigating away? Do you want a delay before nagivating?

Comment: yes, I want to be able to change the image and then navigate @MikaelDúiBolinder

Comment: @amarotati, so you'd like a short delay, like 500 ms or 1000 ms, before the navigation starts?

Answer (score 1):

The code in the `CalendarioClick.Tapped` is `synchronous` and they will execute in order. The `imageSoure` really changed before you push to a new page, however the process of changing is very fast and you can't even figure it out.

**Solution:**

You can add a short delay before push to a new page. You can define the delay time whatever you what.

```
var CalendarioClick = new TapGestureRecognizer();
              CalendarioClick.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
                  {
                      CmdCalendario.BackgroundColor = Color.Pink;
                      //Delay 2000ms, change the time you want here
                      await Task.Delay(2000);
                      Navigation.PushAsync(new CalendarioFiscal());

                  }; 
        CmdCalendario.GestureRecognizers.Add(CalendarioClick);
```

Refer :[Async and Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FlexButton](https://github.com/robinmanuelthiel/flexbutton) for simulate click on images

```
<flex:FlexButton
    WidthRequest="76"
    HeightRequest="76"
    CornerRadius="38"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Icon="lightbulb.png"
    ForegroundColor="#ffffff"
    HighlightForegroundColor="#49516F"
    BackgroundColor="#6279B8"
    HighlightBackgroundColor="#8EA4D2" />
```